# How to print a string into a array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, pdo

I tried to print a `string` into a `array`.

The form will be submitted trough a array. The amount of forms is unknow because user is allowed to add extra inputs if needed (Order system).

To run my `validation` of the form it needs to be like this:

```
$toxValidate = new toxValidate();
    $toxValidation = $toxValidate->check('$_POST', array(
        'part1' => array('required' => TRUE),
        'part2' => array('required' => TRUE),
        'part3' => array('required' => TRUE),
        'part4' => array('required' => TRUE),
        'part5' => array('required' => TRUE)
    ));
```

But because we dont know how many `inputs` it will be, there needs for every input one line of: `'part1'    => array('required' => TRUE),`.

This is what i tried:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($part); $i++){
        $parts .= "part".$i." => array('required' => true)";
        $t0x = $t0x + 1;
        if($t0x < count($part)){
            $parts .= ', ';
        }
    }
```

This would be the `var_dump` output of `$parts` when submitting 3 forms

```
''part0' => array('required' => true), 'part1' => array('required' => true), 'part2' => array('required' => true)'
```

That looks exactly what needs to be printed in:

```
$toxValidation = $toxValidate->check($_POST, array(
#HERE#
));
```

i tried with print and echo which i allready tought wouldt work.

How can i print `$parts` into the array.

**Update**

HTML Form:

```
<div id="form">
                            <p class="order">
                            <label  style="margin-left:20px;">Partnumber:</label><br />
                            <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" id="part" name="part[]" placeholder="SP partnumber" />
                            </p>
                            <p class="order" >
                            <label style="margin-left:20px">Qty</label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty[]" style="margin-left:20px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />
                            <p class="order">
                            <label style="margin-left:20px">Price</label><br>
                            <input type="text"  style="margin-left:20px;" class="text small" id="price" placeholder="Price" tabindex="-1" readonly /><br>
                          </p>

                        </div><p>
```

jQuery to add a other line of inputs:

```
    $('#addpart').click(function(){
  var loop = $('#loop').val();
  var html;
  html = '<p>';
  html += '<input type="text" name="part[]" style="margin-left:20px;" class="text medium" id="part" placeholder="SP partnumber" />';
  html += '<input type="text" name="qty[]" style="margin-left:20px;" class="text small" placeholder="Qty" />';
  html += '<input type="text" style="margin-left:20px;" class="text small" id="price" placeholder="Price" tabindex="-1" readonly />';
  html += '</p>';
  for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    $("#form").append(html);
}

});
```

**Update 2**

But there also needs to be other 'inputs' to be check. Like Purchase order, backorder, date. See below:

```
$toxValidation = $toxValidate->check('$_POST', array(
            'po'            => array('required' => TRUE),
            'date'      => array('required' => TRUE),
            'bo'            => array('required' => TRUE),
            'remarks'   => array('required' => TRUE),
#PARTS HERE#
    ));
```

Comment: SHow an example of the HTML

Comment: Post updated with HTML and jQuery source.

Comment: Something like: `$options = []; for ($i = 0; $i < count($part); $i++) { $options['part' . ($i + 1)] = array('required' => true); }  $toxValidation = $toxValidate->check('$_POST', $options);`?

Comment: @Cyclonecode I answered your comment in my question at the bottom.